# Open video page at Youtube in full screen mode programmatically

Tags: javascript, wpf

I built a WPF application that attempts to navigate to a URL in Youtube that contains a video. I want the video to be played in full screen mode when opened as if the user manually clicked the full screen mode button. I know that such things can be done using Javascript. Can someone show me the way how to do it in a WPF application using Visual Studio? Or is there another way to do this?

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the URL to an embedded one, just parse the video id from URL and 
use the following format, still not full screen though.

`"https://www.youtube.com/embed/{0}?autoplay=1"`

Ex:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/UkWd0azv3fQ?autoplay=1

Comment: Thank you. That almost solved, but now the video doesn't start automatically as it does when I simply start the URL. Any idea how to do this?